# Asp.net Role Authorize Tag not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using Roles an asp.net core 3.1 i have decorated my method as such

```
// GET: MISObjects/Details/5
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id) {
  if (id == null) {
      return NotFound();
  }
  var mISObject = await _context.MISobject
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
     if (mISObject == null) {
         return NotFound();
 }

 return View(mISObject);
}
```

For Some Reason My view is saying access denied even though I have the user in the Manager role as per below.

[image]

You can see here he is in the manager role as should be.

[image]

My Services Config.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddDbContext<MISDBContext>
    (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MISDBContext>().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();  //<---- add this line 
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();            
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("readpolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager", "User"));
            options.AddPolicy("writepolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager","Agent"));
        });
}
```

Does anybody know why its still thinking I dont have a role of manager. And should I limit my end user to certain role list instead of it being dynamic.

Comment: Are you sure the current logged in user is the user with the role "Manager? "Does it not work only when the role is a manager, what about other roles? I see that you also use the policy based role checks, is it ok or still has the same problem?

Comment: @mj1313 Yes it is the user attached I think I neeed to however do something on the login page to save the claim against a cookie but I dont know how to do that.